# How to search file name that contains asterisk (*)?

Tags: finder, macos, filesystem, search

I want to search file name that contains asterisk (*), e.g.

```
*abc.jpg
xy*z.pdf
123*.txt
```

How can I do that in Finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just type `*`. It isn't treated any different than other characters:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just realized that I need to use advanced search with name contains *, so that any * inside documents will be filtered out. Your answer is correct.

Comment: I tested that as well, and it seems to work as well when using the 'Name matches' option.